# ng2-bootstrap with webpack - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: angular, webpack, ng2-bootstrap

Im trying to integrate ng2-bootstrap with webpack using the base template [enter link description here](https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/tree/master/Angular2_CLI_Full_Project). However I seem to not be able to get the ng2-bootstrap integration successful.

Below is my web pack configuration,

```
"use strict";

var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './app/main.ts',
        'vendors': './app/vendors.ts',
        'polyfills': './app/polyfills.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: './wwwroot',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].bundle.map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html|css)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['vendors', 'polyfills'] }),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin(
            [
                './wwwroot/'
            ]
        ),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 9000
    }
};
```

Below is my import,

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tabs';
```

However when I run the application the error is as below,
[image]

For some odd reason the ng2-bootstrap code does not seem to come throught to the browser.

Hope you can provide me a quick fix to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAuFy.png)

你可以像我这样处理，就好了

Comment: [so] is an English-only site. Please post in English. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/1402846) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.